# MVC.net asynchronous response(s) to client/JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I am looking for a possible solution(s) for my requirement,
From ASP.NET MVC Controller action method we invoke multiple asynchronous calls to multiple DB's. These call(s) will return data back to callback method. Callback method maintain static dictionary and stores data based on user-key(unique).

Currently we implemented as, polling to server of data availability which will be stored in a dictionary based on the user key.

I am looking other possible solutions? What is the best way to return data to JavaScript and why?

Comment: I am not clearly understand what do you want. Do you want update data on client every time when data comes from one of your db's, or you want get data from all db's asynchronously and then give it to client?

Comment: 2nd statement is correct. View is already returned to client, to identify the client we maintain key to whom we need to send the data.

Comment: In this case, why are you use polling and not use simple ajax request with callback?

Comment: Let me recap the flow-> Action method returns the view back to UI, within the action method we make couple of asynchronous calls to different systems. We need to update the response back to client in load balanced environment. To identify different clients, we created unique key for each client and client will poll to server for data availability. Hope you understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Polling with javascript for db updates? have you thought about using SignalR (http://signalr.net/)?

Comment: For some reason, no 3rdParty products allowed. :-(

Comment: SignalR is a Microsoft product is an considered part of the asp.net 4.5 stack. http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/videos/signalr-and-web-sockets

Comment: I agree what you said, but not part of MS product, getting approval is not possible. So looking for different solution.